# When assigning value into an Array it returned Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So basically I am trying to get the value from the database and form it into a list so that I can assign each one of them to a dynamic input tag. 
View

```
@foreach (var item in (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AppendTab)
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name[Convert.ToInt32(item.Text)],
new { id = "txtName-" + item.Value, placeholder = "", @class = "form-control"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNo[Convert.ToInt32(item.Text)],
new { id = "txtPhoneNo-" + item.Value, placeholder = "", @class = "form-control"})
/* And Many others field */

}
```

Controller

```
List<Student> Model = _StudentBLL.GetAll(SchoolId); // Action that gets the list

if (Model.Count != 0)
{
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        view.Name[counter] = item.Name;
        view.PhoneNo[counter] = item.PhoneNo;
        
        counter++;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: check the stacktrace of the exception and find out exactly in which line the error occurs. Somewhere there is a variable which points to null which you haven't handled in the code

Comment: @Beingnin It is referring  to this line ```view.Name[counter] = item.Name;```

Comment: What is `view`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the view is just to let you guys know that the html to append to a dynamic input tag that is based on database  student amount

Comment: Didn't quite get what you said.. but did  you debug the code and check if `view` or `view.Name` is not null?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya ```view``` is a ```viewmodel``` that pass the value from ```Model``` to the ```view.cshtml```. ```View.Name``` is not null

Answer (score 0):

> @Beingnin It is referring to this line `view.Name[counter] = item.Name;` – FENR1R Ace 2 hours ago
> `View.Name` is not null – FENR1R Ace 1 hour ago

If nothing on the left hand side of the = is null then it must be that your `GetAll` put a null thing in the Model. This model, for example, will also crash with a null reference in the same way:

```
List<Student> Model = new List<Student>();
Model.Add(null);
```

How it gets there, is for you to figure out.. You could just exclude them:

```
foreach (var item in Model.Where(s => s != null))
```

.. but you should try and find out why they're happening in the first place, so it doesn't trip you up elsewhere in the code when you use GetAll again.

Ultimately, NullRef exceptions are typically very easy to debug; the code crashes and stops, the debugger opens and you just point to every word, or select highlight every expression and then point to it,  on the line with your mouse, see which one makes the tooltip say "null". You can also open the immediate window and paste bits of the code line into it and run it, looking for where it says null, e.g pasting `?item` into it should say `null` in your case